# How can I randomly choose between multiple values, in an Array or not, each with it's own probability? in Java

Tags: java, random, probability

I'm building a very simple text based Russian Roulette "game", and as I was making a 7 slot bulletChamber array, I kinda realized I'm only storing two values, which are either "there's a bullet" or "there's not a bullet".

and I'm just wondering if there's a way where I can randomly choose between two variables where each one has it's own probability ex 5/7 for no bullet and 2/7 for bullet?

Comment: put the code that you try..

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just multiply Math.random() by the total number of chances and check for >= the number of (in this case) bullets:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println((Math.random() * 7) >= 2 ? "Click" : "Bang!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a good answer but it works...

```
 bullets = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1];
```

if you random-ed from 0 to 6 (indexes of the array), you will have 5/7 chance of not-firing a bullet (getting 0 at bullets[randomNum]), and 2 chances of firing a bullet (getting 1 at bullets[randomNum]).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static List<Boolean> getSlotsList(int bullets, int emptySlots) {
    List<Boolean> shoots = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bullets; i++) {
        slots.add(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < emptySlots; i++) {
        slots.add(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(shoots);
    return shoots;
}
```

You can use the method above to create a list with the probabilities you need. And then you could remove the elements and check if there is a bullet:

```
/* Remove element from the list, and check the result */
List<Boolean> shoots = getSlotsList(2, 5);
if (shoots.remove(0) == true) {
    /* There is a bullet */
} else {
    /* Empty sloot */
    /* You could use the list again with the new bullet probabilities */
}
```